# Tomcat долго запускается (17 минут)

Tags: ubuntu, веб-программирование, tomcat, vps

Арендовал VPS, Ubuntu 14.04, установил туда Tomcat 8. В первый раз запустился нормально. Ура. Выключил. Включил. Не отвечает на запросы. Мучился довольно долго, в итоге просто написал

```
/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

и стал дальше сёрфить инет. **Спустя 17 минут он заработал!** Я получил вот такой вывод в консоли: http://pastebin.com/WHZv9ssy

Как видно шаг

> 01-May-2015 22:13:02.183 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

длился 17 минут! Что это может быть такое? В какую сторону копать?

Дополнение: Судя по  статистике сервера, в это время не было повышенной нагрузки на процессор, занятой оперативки было 170 из 1024 мб, никаких дисковых операций не совершалось.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Собственно, нашёл решение. Нужно заменить в файле

```
$JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

строку

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

на строку

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

---

<sup>Оригинал ответа: [«Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431922/tomcat7-starts-too-late-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64-digitalocean).</sup>